# C# Windows Service no Folder access

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I wrote a C# Windows service that should check a folder at a certain interval and then write information about it to an MS SQL database. I have added a typical project installer to this, which creates the service e.g. as "LocalSystem". As a setup I used the Andvanced Installer. As soon as I run the setup (on my PC) everything works perfectly. When I run this on a terminal server or other local PC, it fails to do the folder part. He simply does not check the folders, but can write to the database. I've researched and it's because the servixe can't interact with the desktop. Does anyone have an idea here or is the approach with the desktop interaction wrong? I would appreciate any help and wish you a nice day! :)

Comment: Does the account running the service on the server has read access to the folder? you can create a log file or create a log entry in the windows event log to see if it is doing something on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the SQL Connection..  Service itself was completely fine.